# Непонятная проблема программы android y xiaomi

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение на андроид. Я тестировал это приложение на эмуляторе Genymotion ( Samsung Galaxy S7/S8). Но вот вчера я решил протестировать данное приложение на реальном устройстве. В android studio я использовал функцию построение apk-файла и потом его перекинул его на телефон (под рукой просто не было кабеля к телефону) у меня телефон Huawei Honor 8. Запустилось у меня на телефоне все нормально и выглядело и работало так как и на эмуляторе. Потом я перекинул программу еще нескольким коллегам на такие телефоны - Samsung (Galaxy S7, Xiaomi, Samsung не известной мне модели, старенький Sony). В итоге на всех телефонах программа работала отлично, а вот на Xiaomi что-то (не знаю что) пошло не так. Все ресурсы не подгрузились, это включает в себя иконку приложения, все строковые ресурсы, и может еще то что я не заметил. Само приложение тупило и в итоге слетело. Может проблема в какой-то совместимости, я уже так думал, на Xiaomi стоит andoroid 8.1, то есть последний, я тестировал на андроид 8 на эмуляторе, у меня стоит 7 на huawei. В чем проблема даже представить не могу. Если кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией помогите понять в чем мой косяк.

Comment: на смартфонах семейства XIAOMI стоит не чистый android, а MIUI. Возможно проблема в этом. У меня на руках есть XIAOMI MI6 c Android 8.0. Если хочешь, можешь скинуть протестировать

Comment: ну вот у меня на телефоне стоит emui то все работает а на xiaomi почему-то не работает, и я думаю это мой косяк или их))

Comment: Ну если хотите протестировать пишите. Версия Android: 8.0.0. Версия MIUI: Global, 9.5.8.0

Comment: ок спасибо, буду писать, просто тут проблема с сервером вылезла))