# Определить причину падения приложения на телефоне android

Tags: android

Я разрабатываю приложение на андроид, и само собой его тестирую. Обычным делом при тестировании приложения являются падения приложения, чаще всего эти падения происходят из-за видимых причин, что-то не учтено в коде. Но вот проблема возникла на устройстве находящемся далеко от меня и у меня нету возможности посмотреть логи и причину падения. Почему-то не подгружены строковые ресурсы и много других косяков, которых почему-то нету на подавляющем количестве телефонов. Я уже задавал подобный вопрос [Непонятная проблема программы android y xiaomi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860893/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-android-y-xiaomi) но когда падение произошло на другом телефоне. Почему-то программа крашится(( Может есть какие-то очевидные причины. Вот на данный момент мне сказали что приложение упало на телефоне Samsung. Мне удалось подключить проблемный телефон и получить вроде как причину падения:

```
08-06 15:47:45.351 3394-3394/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getAllowedCarriers: CommandException: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
08-06 15:47:45.355 3394-3394/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getAllowedCarriers: CommandException: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

но опять таки я не уверен. Я просто не могу понять почему на большинстве телефонов программа работает а на некоторых не работает? 
код на котором падает приложение:

```
 submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendPost();
            }
        });


 public void sendPost() {
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final String a = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final String b = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        //retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        mAPIService.auth(new Post(a, b)).enqueue(new Callback<GetToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<GetToken> call, @NonNull Response<GetToken> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Post submitted to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
                    btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1cd000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    //TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.access_token);
                    String token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAccess_token();
                    //txt.setText(token);
                    startActivity(intent);


                    tok_pref = getSharedPreferences("access_token",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = tok_pref.edit();
                    editor.putString(ACCESS_TOKEN,token);
                    editor.commit();


                    saveData();

                    titleEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                btn.setEnabled(false);
                                findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            } else {
                                btn.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                      int after) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<GetToken> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
Заранее
```

спасибо за помощь и ценные советы.

Comment: Ну вы хоть напишите, в каком методу оно падает. Проблема может быть как в кривом провайдере мобильной связи, так и в реализации методов вендором.

Comment: setOnClickListener это тот метод, при нажатии на кнопку приложение падает

Comment: Код покажите, что там внутри `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: ок я понял)) сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: У вас там `LoginActivity` стартует. Проблема где-то в ней.

Comment: я это понял, дальше этой активити приложение не пошло)) а можно как-то посмотреть логи падения приложения не имея данного телефона под рукой? я же не могу посмотреть логи, может есть какой-то способ, что-бы я смог задать вопрос с определенной ошибкой

Comment: Если повезёт, то лог может прийти в гугл консоль разработчика, если приложение из стора скачано. Или он может посмотреть в Logcat, если телефон рутован. Или вам добавить в приложение возможность отправлять логи и попросить человека отправить логи.

Comment: это я так понял нужно сделать возможность снимать и отправлять логи по почте? это очень сложно?)

Comment: Можете отдельным вопросом задать. Я недавно такое реализовывал для нашей игры, поделюсь кодом.

Comment: ок, сейчас задам...